# How to avoid Spring Security redirect loop when using custom form login?

Tags: spring-security

### App security scenario:

- Spring MVC app running 3 instances on PaaS
- App is split in to 2 security domains. Managed w/ 2 DispatchServlets located at `/app` and `/kmlservice`
- App must use https on all pages except for any paths within `/kmlservice`
- App must use custom login page to access all paths within `/app`
- App must use persistent remember-me scheme with LDAP auth

When we converted to https, we are getting infinite redirect loops when attempting to navigate to the `/app/login` page or any other page.  In fact even unprotected pages infinitely reroute to themselves.

### Here is an example of the redirect logs we are seeing on attempting to navigate to `/app/login`:

```
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/login; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint - Redirecting to: https:/some_url.com/app/login
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https:/some_url.com/app/login'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/kmlservice/**'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/resources/**'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/**'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /app/login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/logout'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/accessdenied'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/useful_path'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/help'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/app/login'; against '/app/login'
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/login; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint - Redirecting to: https:/some_url.com/app/login
stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https:/some_url.com/app/login'
```

### Here's what the config looks like:

```
<http pattern="/kmlservice/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http pattern="/app/**" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/app/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/app/accessdenied" default-target-url="/app" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/logout" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/accessdenied" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/useful_path"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_HAS_ACCESS')" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/help" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/app/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
        data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</http>
```

I have tried to remove 
`<intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />`
which seemed to make no difference

Is there any other useful config I could provide?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If https terminates at your router, as is often the case with PaaS configurations, then your servlet container needs some way to work out whether the incoming request was actually secure or not. Spring Security uses the standard servlet API method [isSecure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29) to decide whether it needs to redirect or not. I'd guess that in your case, the servlet container can't tell whether the external request to the router was made over HTTPS or not.

Tomcat, for example, can be configured with the [RemoteIpValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) to check for particular headers and set the request properties accordingly. I don't know whether you have any control over this, but you there's an [equivalent filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RemoteIpFilter.html) which you can use instead. Of course this also requires that you know how your PaaS is setup and whether it forwards headers like `X-Forwarded-Proto` to your app at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is going in indefinite loop because URL */app/login* is secured as it is marked with `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.

Change the `access` value to *permitAll*

```
<intercept-url pattern="/app/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances

Basically you can use 1st filterChainApi with the ".securityMatcher" for your api and 2nd filterChainMvc for your MVC stuff with .formLogin after .authorizeHttpRequests